# Validate form before submit in 2checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, 2checkout

I Want to prevent form to get submitted So I tried below code,Which usually works .But when I used 2checkout js(https://www.2checkout.com/static/checkout/javascript/direct.js) its not working.

```
<form onSubmit="validate(); return false;" method='post'>
```

Here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0a0th3fy/1/

And below is sample code

```
<form onSubmit="validate(); return false;" action='https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='sid' value='1303908' />
    <input type='hidden' name='mode' value='2CO' />
    <input type='hidden' name='li_0_type' value='product' />
    <input type='hidden' name='li_0_name' value='invoice123' />
    <input type='hidden' name='li_0_price' value='25.99' />
    <input id="fullname" name='card_holder_name' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='street_address' value='123 Test Address' />
    <input type='hidden' name='street_address2' value='Suite 200' />
    <input type='hidden' name='city' value='Columbus' />
    <input type='hidden' name='state' value='OH' />
    <input type='hidden' name='zip' value='43228' />
    <input type='hidden' name='country' value='USA' />
    <input type='hidden' name='email' value='example@2co.com' />
    <input type='hidden' name='phone' value='614-921-2450' />
    <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Checkout' />
</form>
```

and javascript

```
function validate(){
    alert("validating");
    if($("#fullname").val()==""){
        alert("enter name");   
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `jQuery`'s `formSubmit event` ?

**Try this:**

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    alert("validating");
    if ($("#fullname").val() == "") {
        alert("enter name");
        $("#tco_lightbox").hide();
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        return true;
    }

});
```

Learn more about [**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: I tried it ,Its not working ..check http://jsfiddle.net/0a0th3fy/9/ , ..first leave the input empty and submit..then try to type again in input field...its struck

Comment: That's something `tco_lightbox` overlapping all over the screen, is it coming from `direct.min.js` ?

Comment: In that case, just hide that `in-case of textbox is empty`

Comment: Perfect :) , I have been struggling for 5 hours and 2checkout cant help

Comment: Hey , Same code http://jsfiddle.net/0a0th3fy/13/ is not working in production https://pandatracking.com/register/test.php ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74838/discussion-between-moksh-shah-and-vishnu).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it's worked.
Are you sure you include jquery?

```js
    
    function validate(){
    alert("validating");
    if($("#fullname").val()==""){
        alert("enter name");   
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }    
}
```

```html
I tried your code, and it's worked.
Are you sure you include jquery?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

<form onSubmit="validate(); return false;" action='' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='sid' value='1303908' />
    <input type='hidden' name='mode' value='2CO' />
    <input type='hidden' name='li_0_type' value='product' />
    <input type='hidden' name='li_0_name' value='invoice123' />
    <input type='hidden' name='li_0_price' value='25.99' />
    <input id="fullname" name='card_holder_name' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='street_address' value='123 Test Address' />
    <input type='hidden' name='street_address2' value='Suite 200' />
    <input type='hidden' name='city' value='Columbus' />
    <input type='hidden' name='state' value='OH' />
    <input type='hidden' name='zip' value='43228' />
    <input type='hidden' name='country' value='USA' />
    <input type='hidden' name='email' value='example@2co.com' />
    <input type='hidden' name='phone' value='614-921-2450' />
    <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Checkout' />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try in jsfiddle , stackoverlflow dont open or submit form